# Replace this yellow capacitor 205K 300V with different type?

Tags: capacitor

I've been trying to find a replacement capacitor for the one in the attached picture. I have been looking for a 2uF 300V according to the indication of the 205K (2,000,000) and what I can usually find on many different websites is a 2.2uF and 400V. From what I remember, the voltage doesn't matter as long as it is higher but 0.2uF more is already 10% higher. I'm also confused with the different names I find, axial film, metallised polyester film, polypropylene film etc. etc. From the image I even found the Taiwanese manufacturer (apparently called Tenda). My question is can I replace it with another type of capacitor, e.g. electrolytic. This capacitor is on a circuit which belongs to a Scholl foot massager and is near where a small fan gets its power from an RB157 rectifier. The fan is used to produce cool air to sooth the feet. The symbol on the circuit board is that of a non-polarised capacitor. The physical size is 31mm x 14mm x 10mm (it is an oval shape). Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could I use it in my broken hifi? It looks very similar to one that is broken and it also resides near a small fan and gets power from a bridge rectifier? Could you answer that?

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/film-capacitors/62?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv16=317190&sf=1&FV=1989%7C0%2Cmu2%C2%B5F%7C2049%2C-8%7C62%2C1293%7C213650%2C1293%7C221502%2C1293%7C237347%2C1293%7C256165%2C1293%7C260046%2C1293%7C273330%2C1293%7C277633%2C1293%7C286566%2C1293%7C290984%2C1293%7C292446%2C1293%7C299382&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=500

Comment: @Andyaka, sorry, can't answer that. And by similar, what exactly do you mean? Any markings on your capacitor?

Comment: @salvu precisely you can't answer that and neither can anyone. Now think about the question you are asking and how similar it is.

Comment: @Andyaka, I asked because I am finding it really difficult to find this capacitor locally. The link kindly provided by Cristobol is a US website and although I tried the EU website, the cost of shipping 1 capacitor would be around 35euro. So that was the reason behind my question. Certain websites simply do not ship to my country or if they do, they simply discourage someone to order by asking exorbitant prices for shipping.